# Bipartite Matching finding maximum cover

Tags: algorithm, graph

There is [Google Code Jam Problem](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/11254486/dashboard#s=p2&a=2). I came to know that problem is solved using Bipartite matching. But i could not understand how to get final answer using number of match.
Here is sudo code

```
int match=0;
// Right - Right one String
// Left  - Left one String
for(int i=0;i<Right.size();i++)
match+=match_found(i)
```

Finally Why these Two lines of Code

```
int need = match + (Right.size() + Left.size() - match * 2);
int answer = n- need;
```

Why is should not be `answer = n-match`

Can you please explain this. That would be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover#Algorithms):

> A smallest edge cover can be found in polynomial time by finding a maximum matching and extending it greedily so that all vertices are covered

This problem asks you to find the minimum number of edges to cover all the vertices.  This is equal to the number of edges in the maximum matching (match) plus the number of additional edges that need to be added in the greedy extension.

The maximum matching covers 2*match vertices, which means there must be x = (Right.size()+Left.size()-2*match) vertices still uncovered.

Therefore we need to add x additional edges in the greedy extension process, and the total number of edges is match+x.

Comment: for `x` edges we could not find the match so that should be fake ? i am right....

Comment: Not quite.  There are `match` real topics that introduce two new words, and `x` real topics that introduce one new word.

Comment: x real topics that introduce one new word.....but we could not find any pair for them... so why `x` real  topics are subtracted from `n` can you please explain me this...

Comment: The total number of real topics is `match+x`.  The total number of real and fake topics is `n`.  Therefore the total number of fake topics is `n - match - x`.

Comment: why `x` is included in real topic as we can't find a match for x topic using bipartite matching.......

Comment: Suppose we had two topics "Planet Earth" and "Planet Mars".  The maximum matching will be of size 1 (e.g.  "Planet Earth"), but this leaves one word (Mars) umatched, and so both topics must have been real ones.